# Want pulldown on gpio pin

Tags: kernel, device-tree

I would like to have the default for certain input pins be a weak pulldown.  I am using a sama5d36 running Debian 4.12.8.  I modified the dts file as follows:

```
ahb {
    abp {
        pinctrl@fffff200 {
            board {
                pinctrl_inputs: input_pins {
                    atmel,pins = 
                        <AT91_PIOC 26 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_PULL_DOWN>,
                        <AT91_PIOC 27 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_PULL_DOWN>,
                        <AT91_PIOA 30 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_PULL_DOWN>,
                        <AT91_PIOA 31 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_PULL_DOWN>;
                };
            };
        };
    };
};

myInputs {
    compatible = "atmel,at91sam9x5-pinctrl", "atmel,at91rm9200-pinctrl";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_inputs>;
};
```

Just wanted to add that I do see PULL_DOWN in /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/ahb:apb:pinctrl@fffff200/pinconf-pins:

```
pin 30 (pioA30): PULL_DOWN|DRIVE_STRENGTH_MED
pin 31 (pioA31): PULL_DOWN|DRIVE_STRENGTH_MED
pin 90 (pioC26): PULL_DOWN|DRIVE_STRENGTH_MED
pin 91 (pioC27): PULL_DOWN|DRIVE_STRENGTH_MED
```

but /sys/class/gpio/pioA30 still shows a value of 1:

```
direction -> in
active_low -> 0
value -> 1
```

Same for the other pins (PioA31, pioC26, pioC27).  I don’t need this pin to be active low I just added that to show that the input is high with nothing connected, something I verified with a scope.

Update:  I added the following pins and they actually work:

```
                    <AT91_PIOD 6 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_PULL_DOWN>,
                    <AT91_PIOD 7 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_PULL_DOWN>;
```

which confuses me even more.  I checked /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/ahb:apb:pinctrl@fffff200/pinmux-pins and all the pins show as follows:

```
pin 102 (pioD6): (MUX UNCLAIMED) (GPIO UNCLAIMED)
pin 103 (pioD7): (MUX UNCLAIMED) (GPIO UNCLAIMED)
```

Anyone experienced anything similar?

Comment: Perhaps in [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) you will get the answer more quickly.

Comment: @k.Cyborg The `sama5d36` device OP mentioned isn't Raspberry Pi. Doesn't fit.  It also doesn't fit https://electronics.stackexchange.com since the question is more about Linux rather than electronics or the MCU device OP uses.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know :-(

Comment: have you tried probing the pins externally with a multimeter to confirm it is, in fact, a logic low?

Comment: Also, what revision of the kernel are you using (`uname -rv`)?

Comment: @imbuedHope I did use a scope and validate that the pin was indeed high and the kernel version is 4.12.8.

Comment: Just as a sanity check are all the pins marked GND on the mcu connected to ground?

Comment: Yea, good grounds and it does appear the pins at reset are input pull-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up a node in the device tree (dts) requires a compatible node like gpio-keys or gpio-leds.  You can't just make up a node like I was trying to do.  since the line I need is part of SPI BLE I added it to my spi1 node as follows:

```
        spi1: spi@f8008000 {
            cs-gpios = <0>, <0>, <0>, <0>;
            pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_spi1 &pinctrl_ble_irq>;
            dmas = <0>, <0>;
            status = "okay";
            spidev@0 {
                compatible = "semtech,sx1301";
                spi-max-frequency = <10000000>;
                reg = <0>;
            };
        };

        pinctrl@fffff200 {
            board {
                pinctrl_ble_irq: ble_irq {
                    atmel,pins =
                        <AT91_PIOB 14 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_PULL_DOWN>,
                        <AT91_PIOB 20 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_PULL_DOWN>,
                        <AT91_PIOB 22 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_PULL_DOWN>,
                        <AT91_PIOB 26 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_PULL_DOWN>,
                        <AT91_PIOC 17 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_PULL_DOWN>,
                        <AT91_PIOD 6 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_PULL_DOWN>,
                        <AT91_PIOD 15 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_PULL_DOWN>,
                        <AT91_PIOE 16 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_PULL_DOWN>,
                        <AT91_PIOE 23 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_PULL_DOWN>,
                        <AT91_PIOE 31 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_PULL_DOWN>,
                        <AT91_PIOD 8 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_PULL_DOWN>;
                };
            };
        };
```

I still don't know why the other pins won't pull down but at least now I am not gettin an error in my boot.  I had to turn on earlyprintk in the kernel in order to see the message.

Update:  was finally able to get pulldown to work. Several pins were pulled up in hardware and thus the ineffectiveness of the pulldown. Several pins were set as LED or used by other peripherals that I disabled. All the pins in the above example did pull down successfully.